# How to find date formats using jquery related to localization

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on localization (globalization), comparing two dates using jquery like startDate and EndDate. My requirement is EndDate should not be lesser than startDate. I have the following code to compare the dates

```
    var startDate = $('#StartDate').val();
    var endDate = $('#EndDate').val();        
    if (startDate.length > 0 && endDate.length > 0) {                    
        return ((new Date(endDate) >= new Date(startDate)))
    }
```

based on this i'm showing the errors. 
This works fine for the default date format(en-US) English. But for the other languages eg: German, Chinese it is not because the date formats are different. 
The Date formats are loaded in a separate  java-script  dynamically upon user's chosen language.

Is there is any way to fix this issue ? If possible can we get the date format of the current loaded application using jquery and use that while comparing the dates ?

Adding some more contents below:

We have rules section in the Jquery.validate.js

```
 rules: function( command, argument ) { 
 // logic for add remove rules..
 });
```

For reference : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules
The Rules which we added for validating the date as follows:

```
$("#EndDate").rules('add', { validateDate: true });
```

The above line i have added after the form.validate()

```
$.validator.addMethod("validateDate", function (value, element) {
    var startDate = $('#StartDate').datepicker("getDate");
    var endDate = $('#EndDate').datepicker("getDate");  
    if (startDate.length > 0 && endDate.length > 0) {                    
        return ((new Date(endDate) >= new Date(startDate)))           
    }
    else if (endDate.length == 0)
        return true;
   }, function () { return dateRangeErrorMessage }
   );
```

So If i use "getDate" for getting the dates from the datepicker we are getting error like "Maximum call stack size exceeded" on the rules section in the jquery.validate.js

Comment: Those input fields, what are they - HTML5 date inputs, normal text fields, …? Does the user input the value manually? If so, are you performing any kind of validation on that? // In general: You should never compare data based on any kind of current/local formatting, but always compare the “raw” underlying data.

Comment: Thanks.Yes it's an normal input field , we are selecting dates from the Datepicker control.

Comment: HTML5 type=date, or a normal text input field with a datepicker applied to it via JS?

Comment: It's an Normal input field , I'm selecting dates from the Datepicker control and added one more rule to the validation using below on form validation $.validator.addMethod("validateDate", function (value, element) {var startDate = $('#StartDate').val();
    var endDate = $('#EndDate').val();        
    if (startDate.length > 0 && endDate.length > 0) {                    
        return ((new Date(endDate) >= new Date(startDate)))
    },"message"}.

Comment: This the jQuery UI Datepicker we are talking about? If so, use its [`getDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) method - that returns a Date object, and since that is free from any local formatting, you can compare two of those directly.

Comment: Yes i have tried that. Getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" because of the validation rule is executing continuously.                                                  var startDate = $('#StartDate').datepicker("getDate");
var endDate = $('#EndDate').datepicker("getDate"); like this i'm trying to get the dates.

Comment: What validation rule?

Comment: The rue which we added "$.validator.addMethod() mentioned in above comments. This will get called in the jquery.validate under the rules section                                                                                               rules: function( command, argument ) {                                                          // here will new rules to the field if any                                                      }

Comment: Code in comments is hardly readable; please edit the question to include your current code.

Comment: I have edited the question with actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create the date using a different way like adding the day/month/year. For example:

`var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));`

Once you have the object, don't forget to change the locale property before making operations.

`// for Japanese, applications may want to use the Japanese calendar,
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('ja-JP-u-ca-japanese'));`

You can find all information in this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Hope it helps